# SSL Handshake failure

Tags: nginx, ssl

For a long time I connected to an external API in my application (`ws.audioscrobbler.com:443`), but it suddenly started to deny me a `SSL` handshake during authentication process, according to this traceback:

```
  File "/Users/me/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Which makes the application to hang altogether.

> However, handshake is granted and application works if I change my router to my phone as a hotspot, so the problem must be related to a specific ISP.

**Note**: I have been containerizing the same application using `Docker` lately, and there's been a lot of network meddling, such as configuring `nginx` as proxy, `react` as client, amazon AWS configs etc, so maybe this is related, but I'm not sure, because the problem persists If I run the application only using my Flask developement stage, prior to the above configs.

what could be going on here and how do I properly debug and fix that?

Comment: You should look for problems with your network connectivity.

Comment: apparently there is nothing wrong with my network connectivity. it connects to the internet normally. so I wouldn't even know how to start looking.

Comment: The site ws.audioscrobbler.com is reachable and responds normally, so if you're hanging while connecting to it on one Internet connection but not the other, then network connectivity is the first thing to look at.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'network connectivity'. the network connects to the internet fine, and ping shows there's is no problem with it.

Comment: You're trying to connect to one specific site, and it hangs. But when you change your ISP you can connect successfully. Or did I misunderstand what I thought I read?

Comment: that's right. how do I investigate a problem related to one specific ISP? is ISP synonym to network? because that ISP hangs only with ws.audioscrobbler.com, but works fine with all other sites

Comment: Maybe you're using an obsolete encryption method? Are you using TLS or the old SSL? Maybe the vendor of the site disabled those old protocols.